# C compiler Differences? NUL control character in Char

Tags: c

Below is C code that will generate char array but with explicitly adding Null character or not. The results are unexpected in two compiler and I'm not sure why we even have to explicitly add the Null character?

```
//
//  stringBugorNot.c
//  
//
//

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


 int main(void)
{
     char aString[3] = {'a', 'b','c'};
     char bString[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};

     printf("\n");
     printf("len of a is: %lu\n", strlen(aString));
     printf("len of b is: %lu\n", strlen(bString));

     printf("\n");

     //Portion A

     printf("last element of a is: '%c'\n", aString[strlen(aString)]);
     printf("last element of b is: '%c'\n", bString[strlen(bString)]);

     printf("\n");

     //Portion B

     printf("last element of a is: '%c'\n", aString[strlen(aString) - 1]);
     printf("last element of b is: '%c'\n", bString[strlen(bString) - 1]);


}
```

**Comments**

+clang will give a runtime error because out of bounds on "aString".. makes sense
 +gcc will not give any error and simply output "nothing" the null as expected. But maybe gcc is smarter and adds the null for me? Is the actual memory size different??

---

**Clang OUTPUT ---->**

len of a is: 3

len of b is: 3

bugOrNot.c:16:41: runtime error: index 3 out of bounds for type 'char [3]'

last element of a is: ''

last element of b is: ''

last element of a is: 'c'

last element of b is: 'c'

---

**GCC OUTPUT ---->**

len of a is: 9

len of b is: 3

last element of a is: ''

last element of b is: ''

last element of a is: ''

last element of b is: 'c'

Comment: `aString` - the "4th byte" could be 'anything', no? In one case it's a NUL (0), in the other it is not.. in short: it's buggy code.

Comment: Maybe another way of looking at the output / exploring the question: Why (and by what magic/rules) is CLANG reporting a useful "*runtime error:* index .. out of bounds" message?

Comment: `char aString[3]` is not a "string" because it has no `'\0'` terminator, so passing it to `strlen` is *undefined behaviour*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say

```
char bString[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'};
```

you have properly constructed a null-terminated string.  It is precisely as if you had said

```
char bString[4] = "abc";
```

Since this is a proper, null-terminated string, it is meaningful and legal to call `strlen(bString)`, and you will get a result of 3.

When you say

```
char aString[3] = {'a', 'b','c'};
```

on the other hand, and as I think you know, you have *not* constructed a proper null-terminated string.  Therefore, it is not legal or meaningful to call `strlen(aString)` -- formally, we say that the result is *undefined*, meaning that absolutely anything can happen.

You tried the code with two different compilers, and were surprised to get two different results.  This is perfectly normal.  (It's perfectly normal to get two different results, and it's perfectly normal to be surprised by this, because it *is* pretty surprising, the first few times you encounter it.)

It is *not* the case that one compiler is "smarter" than the other, or that it "guessed" that you were trying to construct a string and so automatically supplied the "missing" `\0` for you.  It was simply a fluke, a random happenstance.  (It is also certainly not the case that one compiler or the other has any kind of a bug.  Again, there's no right result here, so a compiler can't be wrong, no matter what it does.)

If you want to work with strings in C, make sure that they're all properly null-terminated.  If you should ever happen to accidentally do something stringlike with a non-properly-null-terminated string, don't try to interpret the results, don't assume that they mean anything, and especially don't decide that it's the "right" result that you can therefore depend on.  You can't.  It's likely to change for no reason, like when you use a different compiler next week, or when your customer uses your program on vital data instead of test data.

Answer (score 5):

Unexpected behavior that you see is called *undefined behavior* (UB) in the C standard:

- Calling `strlen` on `aString` is UB because there is no null termination
- Dereferencing `aString` at its undefined index is UB, unless the index is 0, 1, or 2
- gcc could insert null terminator inadvertently by aligning `bString` at 4-byte boundary. It doesn’t change the fact that it’s still a UB, though.

Answer (score 3):

In C, a *string* is a sequence of character values *including the nul terminator*.  That terminator is how the various C library routines know where the end of the string is.  If you don't terminate a string properly, library routines like `strlen` and `strcpy` and `printf` with `%s` will all scan past the end of the string into other memory, resulting in garbled output or runtime errors.

The reason you got different results for the length of `a` with the two different compilers is that in the clang case, the byte immediately following the last element of `a` contained 0, whereas in the gcc case the bytes immediately following `a` did not contain 0.

Strictly speaking, the behavior on passing a non-terminated sequence of characters to the string handling routines is *undefined* - the language specification places no requirements on the compiler or runtime environment to "do the right thing", whatever that would be.  You've basically voided the warranty at that point, and pretty much anything can happen.

Note that the C language specification does not require bounds checks on array accesses - the fact that you got the index out of bounds exception for clang is due to the compiler being extra friendly and going beyond what the language standard actually requires.